# Prevent "Important updates are pending" dialog from displaying

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

We have multiple machines we deploy to customers that run our software 24/7. We currently have problems with the windows feature update notice dialog sitting over top our software. We don't mind the update's taking place, and we schedule our machines to reboot on a regular basis. Is there a way to prevent this popup from appearing.

[image]

The machines are not on a domain, but we do have local admin rights to them. The best solution for us would be a policy or registry setting we could set and include on our image that we use for all our deployments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Local Security Policy Editor.
Go to `Computer Configuration` / `Administrative Templates` / `Windows Components` and select `Windows Update` in the right panel.

[image]

Use the `Configure Automatic Updates`, select the option `4 - Auto download and schedule the install`, specifying the schedule that best suits your needs.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

use this link and go thru all steps from an admin cmd prompt:

```
Click Start and type CMD in the search box
Right click Command Prompt and select Run as administrator
Click Yes when asked for permissions


Stop the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer, 
and Windows Update Services by typing the following 
commands at a command prompt:
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
Press Enter after each command you type
Rename the SoftwareDistribution and Catroot2 folder by typing the
commands below in the Command Prompt then press Enter 
after each command you type:
ren C:\Windows\softwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
Restart the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer, and Windows   
UpdateServices by typing the following commands in command prompt:

    net start wuauserv
    net start cryptSvc
    net start bits
    net start msiserver

Type Exit in the Command Prompt to close it
```

Comment: Incorrect answer in all aspect! Don't try this.